# At what point or phase of Application INSTALL.REFERRER broadcast Receiver is called?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-broadcastreceiver, install-referrer

I have registered a BroadcastReceiver in my Android Manifest. It contains an action of INSTALL.REFERRER to receive intents whenever the application get Installed.

I am trying to set a variable by fetching its value from server before the  INSTALL.REFERRER  action intent takes place.

But i am unable to do so before the action intent. Kindly help me with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Install Referrer is called precisely at the first  launch of your app after install. It is then never fired untill you uninstall and reinstall app.